# Haskell's `partition`

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

Learn You a Haskell mentions the `partition` function:

> partition takes a list and a predicate and returns a pair of lists.
>   The first list in the result contains all the elements that satisfy
>   the predicate, the second contains all the ones that don't.

How's my implementation? I'd prefer to avoid the `++` function, but I'm not sure how to avoid it here.

```
partition' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
partition' f []     = ([], [])
partition' f ys = partition'' f ys [] []
                       where partition'' f [] as bs = (as, bs)
                             partition'' f (x:xs) as bs 
                               | f x       = partition'' f xs (as ++ [x]) bs
                               | otherwise = partition'' f xs as (bs ++ [x])
```

Comment: Your current version is not equivalent to the `partition` of `Data.List`. `take 10 $ fst $ partition' (\x -> (x \`mod\` 2 == 0)) [1..]` gives a runtime error. Where as `take 10 $ fst $ partition (\x -> (x \`mod\` 2 == 0)) [1..]` is `[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]`

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca You've found a bug. [I think that's worthy of an answer, not a comment.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1479/9357)

Comment: thank you, @abuzittingillifirca, for finding this bug. thanks too, 200_success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @aled1027 suggests, `partition'` is just a fancy form of `filter`.  Therefore, it would be useful to study how `filter` can be implemented without `++`.

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' _ [] = []
filter' f (x:xs)
  | f x       = x:rest
  | otherwise = rest
  where rest = filter' f xs
```

The key to avoiding `++`, I think, is to force yourself to write `x:` first, then figure out how to fill in everything surrounding it.  The next logical step would be to write

```
  | f x = x:filter' f xs
```

… and the rest should follow naturally.

Here's what I came up with for `partition'` (hover for spoiler):

> `partition' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
> partition' _ [] = ([], [])
> partition' f (x:xs)
>   | f x       = ((x:accepted), rejected)
>   | otherwise = (accepted, (x:rejected))
>   where (accepted, rejected) = partition' f xs`

Comment: Excellent! I used your helpful answer to write your "spoiler" answer. It's so concise - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use filter -- unless you are trying to avoid using filter?  Filter would remove the need for `++`.

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712208/how-do-i-use-the-filter-function-in-haskell).